# Android Studio: Is it possible to get the list of API Calls from installed applications?

Tags: api, android-studio

I came up with an idea that I may be able to analyze app's behavior with API Calls. I couldn't find any information regarding getting the list of API Calls in the document. Is it not possible to get the list of API Calls from installed applications in Android Studio?